# Custom UI for a GCM Notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In [GCM Docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) its given:

> It does not provide any built-in user interface or other handling for
>   message data. GCM simply passes raw message data received straight to
>   the Android application, which has full control of how to handle it.
>   For example, the application might post a notification, display a
>   custom user interface, or silently sync data

But nothing about how to create a custom notification UI.

How to create a custom UI like say a small dialog with 2 buttons etc.., for a GCM notification. Like gmail gives an option to archive or delete the mail from the status bar notification.

**CODE:**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
    ctx = context;
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
    } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
            .equals(messageType)) {
    } else {
        sendNotification(intent.getExtras().getString("msg"));
    }
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
            new Intent(ctx, NotificationsActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            ctx).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    Notification mNotification = mBuilder.getNotification();

    SharedPreferences sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
            GCMDemoActivity.GCM_NOTIF_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long diff = System.currentTimeMillis()
            - sp.getLong("last_gcm_timestamp", 0);
    if (diff > TWO_MINUTES) {
        mNotification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putLong("last_gcm_timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
        editor.commit();
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
}
```

Thank You

Comment: What is in your `GCMIntentService` ?

Comment: I am not using any IntentService, I am building the Notification in the `BroadcastReceiver's onReceive()`

Comment: oops, my bad. i should ask the content of `onReceive()` function.

Comment: What you can do is, create a DialogActivity having custom layout and when you receive any new message, create that activity and show it. This will show message popup with dialog.

Comment: @ChintanRathod that sounds like a advertisement dialog which asks for install some apps if am right. But that doesn't look like a notification. Cant I do something similar in the status bar?

Comment: you can.. why not.. I think you can create a view which handles all the notification like we show in top of websites, those were scrolling with marquee effect. You can display like that. You need to create a base activity for that which have base layout with bottom panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But nothing about how to create a custom notification UI.

Because that has nothing to do with GCM.

> How to create a custom UI like say a small dialog with 2 buttons etc.., for a GCM notification. Like gmail gives an option to archive or delete the mail from the status bar notification.

That is an expanded or "big" notification, as is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Comment: fine. Another thing is the text doesn't come on the top status bar. Always just the icon comes. I have seen apps whose notification message comes on top for like 1-2 seconds and the icon remains.

Comment: @user1537779: That is the ticker text, which you set via `setTicker()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dialog box with two buttons when notification is received from GCM in generateNotification() inside GCMIntentService.java class.